# How to split columns in itextsharp?

Tags: asp.net, itext

I have 200 columns.I want to set 50 columns in one page,Total 4 page.I used

```
doc.NewPage()
```

but it does not affect in my page?How can I split this 200 column as 50 in 4 pages.Now it looks like

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto Split Columns using iTextSharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20042287/auto-split-columns-using-itextsharp)

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do this.

**The first way** is explained in my answer to the question [What's an easy to print "first right, then down"?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/whats-easy-print-first-right-then-down)

In the [TableTemplate](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/pdfptable-and-pdftemplate#937-tabletemplate.java) example, we write the full table to a `PdfTemplate` that is much bigger than a single page:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(15);
table.setTotalWidth(1500);
PdfPCell cell;
for (int r = 'A'; r <= 'Z'; r++) {
    for (int c = 1; c <= 15; c++) {
        cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.setFixedHeight(50);
        cell.addElement(new Paragraph(String.valueOf((char) r) + String.valueOf(c)));
        table.addCell(cell);
    }
}
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
PdfTemplate tableTemplate = canvas.createTemplate(1500, 1300);
table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 0, 1300, tableTemplate);
```

Once the table is completed, you can then distribute the `tableTemplate` object over different pages:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 1500; j += 500) {
    for (int i = 1300; i > 0; i -= 650) {
        clip = canvas.createTemplate(500, 650);
        clip.addTemplate(tableTemplate, -j, 650 - i);
        canvas.addTemplate(clip, 36, 156);
        document.newPage();
    }
}
```

If this is what you want to do, then your question is a duplicate of [itext -- what's an easy to print "first right, then down"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093993/itext-whats-an-easy-to-print-first-right-then-down)

**The second way** is to use the `writeSelectedRows()` method. In this case, your question is a duplicate of [Auto Split Columns using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20042287/auto-split-columns-using-itextsharp) and [Itextsharp: Adjust 2 elements on exactly one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590071/itextsharp-adjust-2-elements-on-exactly-one-page)

The [Zhang](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-4#202-zhang.java) example from the second edition of iText in Action shows you how this method works:

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
// draw the first two columns on one page
table.writeSelectedRows(0, 2, 0, -1, 236, 806, canvas);
document.newPage();
// draw the remaining two columns on the next page
table.writeSelectedRows(2, -1, 0, -1, 36, 806, canvas);
```

The first time, we use `writeSelectedRows`, we draw column 0 to 2 (not included) and row 0 to the total number of rows on a page. The second time, we draw all the columns, starting with column 2, and all the rows.

**The third way** is to adapt the size of your page to the size of your table. This is explained in my answer to the question [How to define the page size based on the content?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-define-page-size-based-content)

Comment: I did not get above mentioned ideas.

Comment: @SemilSebastian Did you try the examples?