# Adjust pdf text dynamically according to Text width using iTextSharp C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext, document

I'm using iTexSharp for PDF in my application. I got a scenario to display some text details (Patient disease details). I have two columns 1st Column displays for Patient Details and 2nd Column displays patients illness. In 2nd Column I have to display the patient disease text from Left to Right in text indent. In PDF I have an Blue Arrow line which will be the middle of the PDF page between two columns. Whenever I have the text length less than 25 characters I'm fine to display the text from left to right align, but when text exceeds more than  20 characters in length I have to adjust little left to right the content but in this case I'm ending up displaying the text from right to left where I see lot of space exist after the text (Disease). Where red line is the starting point of displaying 2nd column text

Text with in 25 chars (Looks' good)
[image]

Text with more than 25 characters
[image]

Below is my code to display the two columns from Table

```
if (patientDetails.DiseaseText.Length > 25 && patientDetails.DiseaseText.Length < 57)
                    welcomeOuterTable.SetWidths(new float[] { 65f, 65f });
                else
                    welcomeOuterTable.SetWidths(new float[] { 97f, 33f });
```

I need to set the second value of new float[] to be the textwidth length in relativeWidths number as example

```
 if (patientDetails.DiseaseText.Length > 25 && patientDetails.DiseaseText.Length < 57)
                        welcomeOuterTable.SetWidths(new float[] { 65f, patientDetails.DiseaseText.Length.Width});
                    else
                        welcomeOuterTable.SetWidths(new float[] { 97f, 33f });
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correct, you want to set the 2nd column width dynamically based on the contents of patientDetails.DiseaseText.

If that is the case, you want to know the rendered width of the text, and if it will fit in one line or not.

These links show how you can calculate the rendered width of a string based on a font. From there you can make a decision about your column width.

[How to calculate the string width in iText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525986/how-to-calculate-the-string-width-in-itext)

[iText -- How do I get the rendered dimensions of text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093488/itext-how-do-i-get-the-rendered-dimensions-of-text)

https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it5kb/faq/how-to-get-the-rendered-dimensions-of-text

Comment: Here I'm trying to add two tables (Table A, Table B) text in one single table (Table C) with two columns. So the requirement is to auto adjust the Table B width according to the content of the table B (In Table B I have an email address which width might change dynamically) if the email width crosses more than 12 chars I have to slightly shift the whole table B content towards little left considering maximum chars allowed for email in table B as 30 chars.